# Log collisions in multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I want to log collisions in multithreading with this simple code

```
    public T DataRef
    {
        get
        {
            Collisions.DetectAndSaveCollision(typeof(T).ToString(), Sync);
            lock (Sync)
            {
                return _tData;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            IsInitialized = true;
            Collisions.DetectAndSaveCollision(typeof(T).ToString(), Sync);
            lock (Sync)
            {
                _tData = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the method caled for add an element in a list of Collisions

```
    public static void DetectAndSaveCollision(string value, object lockObject)
    {
        var acquired = false;
        try
        {
            acquired = Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (acquired)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
            }
            else
            {
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    CollisionCollection.Add(Thread.CurrentThread, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but I'm not sure that it is deadlock free

Comment: I didn't look at "deadlock free", but this has a race condition. If nobody has taken the lock when you call DetectAndSaveCollision, but another thread tries to take the lock *while* DetectAndSaveCollision has it, that other thread will wait, and then when DetectAndSaveCollision releases the lock, that other thread will grab it. DetectAndSaveCollision will then return back to the code outside. Basically, I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but this isn't it.

Comment: Could you tell us which problem you're trying to solve here? Why do you need to somehow detect "collisions" anyway? The locks should make sure two threads doesn't access the same shared state in a conflicting manner, doesn't this work for you? So what if one thread has to wait a few milliseconds before the first thread completes?

Comment: It will be quite hard to create a deadlock situation with just 1 lock, I'm just not sure this code does what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

This is deadlock free because at most one lock is taken at the same time.

As Lasse points out in the comments there is a race condition here because you're acquiring the `Sync` lock twice in a row. So the data won't be exact. If approximate data is enough for you then this is fine.

You can fix the race by not releasing the lock immediately when you got it. Something like this:

```
var acquiredImmediately = Monitor.TryEnter(...); //test lock

if (!acquiredImmediately) {
    Log(...);
    Monitor.Enter(...); //retry by blocking
}

CriticalRegion();

Monitor.Exit();
```

And this needs protection with `finally` of course.